# Get certain items based on their formatting

Tags: python, ironpython

I have a list of values, some are numeric only, others made up of words, others a mix of the two.
I would like to select only those items composed by the combination number, single letter, number.

let me explain, this is my list of values

```
l = ['980X2350', 'DO_UN_HPL_Glas_Links', 'DO_UN_HPL_Glas_Rechts',
     '930x2115', 'DO_UN_HPL_Links', 'DO_UN_HPL_Rechts', '830X2115',
     'Deuropening', 'BF_32_Tourniquets_dubbeledeur_Aluminium']
```

I'd like to just get back:

```
['980X2350', '930x2115', '830X2115']
```

Comment: your have invalid python here, make sure your provide python code that reproducibly creates the list you want to work with

Comment: Right now I have a list of values https://pastebin.com/M1tTMyMG, as a language I can use IronPython or even, if it gets easier, on C #
(I'm working on the grasshopper program which is not really a computer program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a list of strings as input, you can use a regex and a list comprehension:

```
l = ['980X2350', 'DO_UN_HPL_Glas_Links', 'DO_UN_HPL_Glas_Rechts',
     '930x2115', 'DO_UN_HPL_Links', 'DO_UN_HPL_Rechts', '830X2115',
     'Deuropening', 'BF_32_Tourniquets_dubbeledeur_Aluminium']
import re
regex = re.compile('\d+x\d+', flags=re.I)

out = [s for s in l if regex.match(s.strip())]
```

output:

```
['980X2350', '930x2115', '830X2115']
```

Comment: Returns this error:

Error: Runtime error (UnboundNameException): name 'l' is not defined

Comment: `l` should be the list of strings as defined in my example above

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of importing `re` for such trivial matter.

Here is an approach that is more efficient than the regex based one:

```py
allowed = '0123456786x'

def filter_str(lst):
    output = []
    for s in lst:
        c = s.lower().strip()
        if all(i in allowed for i in c) and c.count('x') == 1:
            output.append(s)
    return output
```

---

If the strings must contain two numeric fields:

```py
allowed = '0123456786x'

def filter_str(lst):
    output = []
    for s in lst:
        c = s.lower().strip()
        n = len(c) - 1
        if all(i in allowed for i in c) and c.count('x') == 1 and c.index('x') not in (0, n):
            output.append(s)
    return output
```

`all` function short-circuits (i.e. it stops checking as soon as Falsy value is registered), all Python logical operators also short-circuit, for the `and` operator, the right-hand operand won't be executed if the left-hand operand is Falsy, so my code does look it's longer than the regex based one, but it actually executes faster because regex checks whole strings and does not short-circuit.

Comment: try `filter_str(['x0', '0x', '0x0'])` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a list of strings :

you can store in a counter the number of letters encountered, if this number is exactly equal to 1 and you have encountered some numbers then you can store it to your output list :

```py
a = ['980X2350', 'DO_UN_HPL_Glas_Links', 'DO_UN_HPL_Glas_Rechts', '930x2115', 'DO_UN_HPL_Links',
    'DO_UN_HPL_Rechts', '830X2115', 'Deuropening' ]

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alphabet+= alphabet.upper()
numeric = '0123456789'

numeric_flag = False

output = []

for item in a:
    alphabet_count = 0
    for char in item:
        if char in alphabet:
            alphabet_count += 1
        if char in numeric:
            numeric_flag = True

    if alphabet_count == 1 and numeric_flag:
        output.append(item)

print(output)
# ['980X2350', '930x2115', '830X2115']
```